# Debugging in Visual Studio hangs unless paused and continued

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, f#

I have a .NET Core 2.1 solution containing 2 F# projects, one class library and one executable. When I run the executable project with the command:

```
dotnet run --project ServerProject
```

it shows the [Suave.IO](https://suave.io/) log message immediately:

```
Smooth! Suave listener started in 92.632ms with binding 0.0.0.0:3000
```

However when I try to debug in Visual Studio (2017 or 2019 Preview) nothing appears on the dotnet.exe window at all — unless I pause debugging and continue, at which point it will carry on as usual and display the log message immediately.

I have set breakpoints to try and figure out where it gets stuck but nothing special happens there at all. My code loads some data from a CSV and it somehow gets stuck at the stage where it converts the CSV's rows into some records. All breakpoints and `printf` statements before this function get hit but the subsequent ones don't. And every time I pause debugging it seems to pause at a different point of this cell parsing code, so it's not even hanging in the exact same place every time.

I'm fairly new to the .NET world so I'm not even sure where to start investigating. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Adding this to say that this has been happening consistently for many months now. Any ideas would be really appreciated.